# Appsync & GraphQL: how to filter a list by nested value

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I have an Appsync API generated by Amplify from a basic schema. On the `Article` model, a `category` field is nested within a `metadata` field. I want to build a Query that provides a list of Articles filtered by category. It is not clear to me how to filter on a nested value... I have seen [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532299/gatsby-js-filter-graphql-query-by-nested-object-property) but the analogous answer has not worked.

**AWS GraphQL Transform Schema**

```
type Article @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String!
  text: String!
  metadata: ArticleMetadata!
}

type ArticleMetadata {
  category: Category!
  lastModified: String!
  creationDate: String!
}

enum Category {
  javascript
  java
  ruby
  python
  haskell
}
```

**Generated List Query**

```
export const listArticles = `query ListArticles(
  $filter: ModelArticleFilterInput
  $limit: Int
  $nextToken: String
) {
  listArticles(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
    items {
      id
      title
      description
      text
      metadata {
        category
        lastModified
        creationDate
      }
    }
    nextToken
  }
}
`;
```

**Failing filter query**

```
query listArticlesByCategory($category: String!) {
  listArticles(filter: {category: {eq: $category}}) { 
    items {
      title
      description
      text
      metadata {
        category
        creationDate
        lastModified
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The Appsync console error states that the `category` in `filter: {category: ... }` is an unknown field.

Comment: It looks like you're generating a data type backed by a DynamoDB table, which isn't going to have a filter argument available to it. Try looking into the @searchable directive

Comment: It is backed by DynamoDB, but the auto-generated code for the `list` op includes `$filter: ModelArticleFilterInput`. Examining the `ModelArticleFilterInput` revealed that `metadata` is not included. Not sure why only top-level fields can be filtered upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the Amplify codegen only will operate on top-level filters. You can extend this to include filters for the attributes nested in ArticleMetadata.

You will need to augment the `ModelArticleFilterInput` type to include the category field. Assuming that the metadata field in the article table is backed by a DynamoDB map, you can filter based on the map value. You will need to modify the listArticles resolver's Request Mapping Template VTL to add the filter expression that contains something like `metadata.category = :category` when there is a value for cateogry in the filter argument.

Comment: I didn't have an opportunity to personally verify this, but it aligns with my understanding of Appsync resolvers and Amplify's generated code.

Comment: @Aaron_H can you give or point to an example on how to do this?

Comment: @aaron-h
would you please provide example? https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/6467