# How set limit for nested field in AWS amplify DynamoDB schema?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql, aws-amplify

I have next query

```
export const listCategorys = `query ListCategorys(
  $filter: ModelCategoryFilterInput
  $limit: Int
  $nextToken: String
) {
  listCategorys(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
    items {
      id
      name
      words {
        items {
          id
          en
          ru
          statusLearn
        }
        nextToken
      }
    }
    nextToken
  }
}
`;
```

I want use limit for nested element **words** and try get result with help next query

```
const listCats = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listCategorys, {limit:10, words:{limit:100}}));
```

but this query not work. How right build query?

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very similar to [Appsync & GraphQL: how to filter a list by nested value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132782/appsync-graphql-how-to-filter-a-list-by-nested-value), in that the default Amplify codegen only generates top-level filters/limits.

There's a feature request around this here that you may want to upvote & comment on: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/2311

Otherwise, there isn't a way to do this out-of-the-box yet without modifying the VTL templates.